# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GpioObj while building nethunter kernel

Tags: python, kernel, oppo

hello guys good day today i was building non-existing nethunter kernel for the device oppo A5s but i encountered an error and this is the log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/tools/dct/DrvGen.py", line 26, in <module>
    from obj.ChipObj import ChipObj
  File "/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/tools/dct/obj/ChipObj.py", line 19, in <module>
    from GpioObj import  GpioObj
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GpioObj'
make[1]: *** [/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/scripts/drvgen/drvgen.mk:61: arch/arm64/boot/dts/oppo6765_18511/cust.dtsi] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/tools/dct/DrvGen.py", line 26, in <module>
    from obj.ChipObj import ChipObj
  File "/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/tools/dct/obj/ChipObj.py", line 19, in <module>
    from GpioObj import  GpioObj
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GpioObj'
make[1]: *** [/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/scripts/drvgen/drvgen.mk:61: arch/arm64/boot/dts/mediatek/oppo6765_18511.dtb] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/kali-nethunter-kernel/out'
make: *** [Makefile:150: sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source'

real    0m2.121s
user    0m1.101s
sys     0m0.704s
make: Entering directory '/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/kali-nethunter-kernel/out'
@@@@@@@@@@@ 111 OPPO_BUILD_CUSTOMIZE is 
cp: cannot stat './modules.order': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/Makefile:1259: _modinst_] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source/kali-nethunter-kernel/out'
make: *** [Makefile:150: sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/kali/A5S-8.1-kernel-source'

real    0m0.639s
user    0m0.303s
sys     0m0.285s
[ SUCCESS  ] Kernel build completed
[ QUESTION ] Save .config as nethunter_defconfig? [y/n]
```

i checked the missing modules but they exist within the kernel source i dont understand why this happened

i checked the kernel source if this python module exist and yes it indeed exist then i tried building again i still got the error someone told me hat it may be an python package so i should install it using pip but still didnt work because its not python package im kinda newbie about this so please i need help for this thank you